# How to split charges on invoice line level in netsuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, invoice

On invoice record, there is charge field, which contains charge record link. Single charge field may have multiple charges attached. If item name is same, then its related charges gets attached in the charge field. Is there way to split charges across multiple lines. For example, 3 charges attached for Item A, then 3 lines should set on invoice as,
Item A  Charge1
Item A  Charge2
Item A  Charge3